# How does data shape change during Conv2D and Dense in Keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, flatten

Just as the title says. This code only works Using:

```
x = Flatten()(x)
```

Between the convolutional layer and the dense layer.

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Input
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.optimizers import SGD

# Generate dummy data
x_train = np.random.random((100, 100, 100, 3))
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(np.random.randint(10, size=(100, 1)), num_classes=10)

#Build Model
input_layer = Input(shape=(100, 100, 3))
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu')(input_layer)
x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=[input_layer],outputs=[x])

#compile network
sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd)

#train network
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=10)
```

Otherwise, I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/michael/practice_example.py", line 44, in <module>
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=10)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1435, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1315, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='target')

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 127, in _standardize_input_data
    str(array.shape))

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (100, 10)
```

#### Why would the output have 4 dimensions without the `flatten()` layer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to keras doc,

> Conv2D Output shape
>
> 4D tensor with shape: (samples, filters, new_rows, new_cols) if data_format='channels_first' or 4D tensor with shape: (samples, new_rows, new_cols, filters) if data_format='channels_last'. rows and cols values might have changed due to padding.

Since you are using `channels_last`, the shape of layer output would be:

```
# shape=(100, 100, 100, 3)

x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu')(input_layer)
# shape=(100, row, col, 32)

x = Flatten()(x)
# shape=(100, row*col*32)    

x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
# shape=(100, 256)

x = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)
# shape=(100, 10)
```

#### Error explanation (edited, thanks to @Marcin)

Linking a 4D tensor (shape=(100, row, col, 32)) to a 2D one (shape=(100, 256)) using `Dense` layer will still form a 4D tensor (shape=(100, row, col, 256)) which is not what you want.

```
# shape=(100, 100, 100, 3)

x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu')(input_layer)
# shape=(100, row, col, 32)

x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
# shape=(100, row, col, 256)

x = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)
# shape=(100, row, col, 10)
```

And the error will occur when the mismatch between output 4D tensor and target 2D tensor happens.

That's why you need a `Flatten` layer to flat it from 4D to 2D.

#### Reference

[Conv2D](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv2d)
[Dense](https://keras.io/layers/core/#dense)

Comment: Actually - your answer is wrong. You can apply a `Dense` to `4d` layer. This is where error comes from.

Comment: So I can connect it, but when I provide 2D target values it throws the error?

Comment: Yes @MarcinMożejko is right. Thanks. I just edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

From [`Dense`](https://keras.io/layers/core/#dense) documentation one may read that in case when an input to a `Dense` has more than two dimensions - it's applied only to a last one - and all other dimensions are kept:

```
# shape=(100, 100, 100, 3)

x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu')(input_layer)
# shape=(100, row, col, 32)

x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
# shape=(100, row, col, 256)

x = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)
# shape=(100, row, col, 10)
```

That's why a `4d` target is expected.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "it's applied only to a last one" and "all other dimensions are kept"?

Comment: That it's like a convolution with `(1, 1)` filter size. A `Dense` layer is applied for each pixel in each row and col and result is returned as a pixel map (as shown in an example).