# keras convolutional nerural network - output shape

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

Please forgive my ignorance as I am really new to the area. I am trying to get the correct output shape from my neural network which has 3 Conv2D layers then 2 Dense layers. My input shape is (140, 140, 4), which are 4 grayscale images. When I fit in 1 input, I am expecting an output of (1, 4) but I am getting a shape of (14, 14, 4) here. What am I doing wrong here? Thank you very much for your help in advance!

```
meta_layers = [Conv2D, Conv2D, Conv2D, Dense, Dense]
meta_inits = ['lecun_uniform'] * 5
meta_nodes = [32, 64, 64, 512, 4]
meta_filter = [(8,8), (4,4), (3,3), None, None]
meta_strides = [(4,4), (2,2), (1,1), None, None]
meta_activations = ['relu'] * 5
meta_loss = "mean_squared_error"
meta_optimizer=RMSprop(lr=0.00025, rho=0.9, epsilon=1e-06)
meta_n_samples = 1000
meta_epsilon = 1.0;
    meta = Sequential()
    meta.add(self.meta_layers[0](self.meta_nodes[0], init=self.meta_inits[0], input_shape=(140, 140, 4), kernel_size=self.meta_filters[0], strides=self.meta_strides[0]))
    meta.add(Activation(self.meta_activations[0]))
    for layer, init, node, activation, kernel, stride in list(zip(self.meta_layers, self.meta_inits, self.meta_nodes, self.meta_activations, self.meta_filters, self.meta_strides))[1:]:
        if(layer == Conv2D):
            meta.add(layer(node, init = init, kernel_size = kernel, strides = stride))
            meta.add(Activation(activation))
        elif(layer == Dense):
            meta.add(layer(node, init=init))
            meta.add(Activation(activation))
        print("meta node: " + str(node))
    meta.compile(loss=self.meta_loss, optimizer=self.meta_optimizer)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies in the fact that in Keras with version >= 2.0, a `Dense` layer is applied to the last channel of the inputs (you may read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44972799/how-does-data-shape-change-during-conv2d-and-dense-in-keras/44973278#44973278)). So if you apply:

```
Dense(512)
```

to a `Conv2D` layer with shape `(14, 14, 64)` you'll get the output with shape `(14, 14, 512)` and then `Dense(4)` applied to it will give you output with shape `(14, 14, 4)`. You can call `model.summary()` method to confirm my words.

In order to solve this you need to apply one of the following layers: `GlobalMaxPooling2D`, `GlobalAveragePooling2D` or `Flatten` to the output from the last convolutional layer in order to squash your output to be only 2 dimensional (with shape `(batch_size, features)`.

Comment: is it just an addition of a flatten layer? I have tried adding one after the last convolutional layer and it's giving me this error: Input 0 is incompatible with layer flatten_2: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2

Comment: This seems weird. It looks like you squashed your first convolutional layer.

Comment: Try to also test other layers - with `Pooling` as they may help and speed up computations.

Comment: Do these layers only make a difference in speed? Or they may also affect the training results?

Comment: Adding `GlobalPooling` makes the output from this layer smaller and without any spatial clues. This might help (as it's decreasing the parameter space) or harm (as a model is carrying less information).