# How to compute number of weights of CNN?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

How can we compute number of weights considering a convolutional neural network that is used to classify images into two classes :

- INPUT: 100x100 gray-scale images.
- LAYER 1: Convolutional layer with 60 7x7 convolutional filters (stride=1, valid
  padding).
- LAYER 2: Convolutional layer with 100 5x5 convolutional filters (stride=1, valid
  padding).
- LAYER 3: A max pooling layer that down-samples Layer 2 by a factor of 4 (e.g., from 500x500 to 250x250)
- LAYER 4: Dense layer with 250 units
- LAYER 5: Dense layer with 200 units
- LAYER 6: Single output unit

Assume the existence of biases in each layer. Moreover, pooling layer has a weight (similar to AlexNet)

How many weights does this network have?

## Some Keras code

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D

model = Sequential()

# Layer 1
model.add(Conv2D(60, (7, 7), input_shape = (100, 100, 1), padding="same", activation="relu"))

# Layer 2
model.add(Conv2D(100, (5, 5), padding="same", activation="relu"))

# Layer 3
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

# Layer 4
model.add(Dense(250))

# Layer 5
model.add(Dense(200))

model.summary()
```

Comment: If you create that model in Keras, it will calculate it for you.

Comment: Create the model and call `model.summary()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## TL;DR - For TensorFlow + Keras

Use `Sequential.summary` - [Link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential#summary) to documentation.

**Example usage:**

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import *

model = Sequential([
    # Your architecture here
]);

model.summary()
```

The output for your architecture is:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 94, 94, 60)        3000      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 90, 90, 100)       150100    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 45, 45, 100)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 202500)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 250)               50625250  
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 200)               50200     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 201       
=================================================================
Total params: 50,828,751
Trainable params: 50,828,751
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

That's 50,828,751 parameters.

## Explanation

### Number of weights in a 2D Convolutional layer

For a 2D Convolutional layer having

- `num_filters` filters,
- a filter size of `filter_size * filter_size * num_channels`,
- and a bias parameter per filter

The number of weights is: `(num_filters * filter_size * filter_size * num_channels) + num_filters`

**E.g.:** LAYER 1 in your neural network has

- 60 filters
- and a filter size of 7 * 7 * 1. (Notice that the number of channels (1) comes from the input image.)

The number of weights in it is: `(60 * 7 * 7 * 1) + 60`, which is `3000`.

### Number of weights in a Dense layer

For a Dense layer having

- `num_units` neurons,
- `num_inputs` neurons in the layer prior to it,
- and a bias parameter per neuron

The number of weights is: `(num_units * num_inputs) + num_units`

**E.g.** LAYER 5 in your neural network has

- 200 neurons
- and the layer prior to it - LAYER 4 - has 250 neurons.

The number of weights in it is `200 * 250`, which is `50200`.

Comment: Flatten and Dense layers I don't think that are needed at my model . Should I add a weight at MaxPooling layer similar to AlexNet ?

Comment: As far as I know, MaxPooling layers don't have weights associated with them. I may be wrong, though.

Comment: Yes , Maxpooling layer does not have a weight . I wrote some fixed code at top post .

Comment: Your model will need a Flatten layer between the Conv2D and Dense layers, or you'll get a ValueError at runtime (while training). A Dense layer expects a 2D tensor as input, but the output of a Conv2D layer is a 4D tensor. Flatten will convert the 4D tensor to a 2D tensor as needed. Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44972799/how-does-data-shape-change-during-conv2d-and-dense-in-keras) for more details. Also, you'll need a Dense layer with 1 neuron at the end of your network because that's the output layer.