# Determining the dimensions of weights for a 3-d Convolution with a 4-d Kernel

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

As the title says I'm looking at determining the proper dimensions for my CNN architecture. First, I obtain the next element of my dataset:

```
train_ds = iter(model.train_dataset)
feature, label = next(train_ds)
```

Where `feature` has dimensions `(32, 64, 64, 4)` corresponding to a batch size of 32, height of 64, length 64, and extended batch size of 4 (not a channel dimension). I initialize my 4-d kernel to pass over my 3-matrix, as I do not want the extended batch size to be convoluted. What I mean by this is in practice I want a 2-d kernel of size `(1, 1)` to pass over each 64 x 64 image, and do the same for the extended batch size without convoluting the extended batch sizes together. So I am in fact doing a `(1, 1)` convolution for each image in parallel with each other. So far I was able to initialize the `kernel` and feed the `conv2d` like so:

```
kernel = tf.constant(np.ones((1, 1, 4, 4)), dtype=tf.float32)
output = tf.nn.conv2d(feature, kernel, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
```

Doing this produces my expected output, `(32, 64, 64, 4)`. But I have absolutely no idea how to initialize the weights so that they work with this architecture. I have something like this:

```
w_init = tf.random_normal_initializer()
input_dim = (4, 1, 1, 4)
w = tf.Variable(
            initial_value=w_init(shape=(input_dim), dtype="float32"),
            trainable=True)

tf.matmul(output, w)
```

But I'm receiving incompatible batch dimensions as I don't know what the `input_dim` should be. I know it should be something like `(num_filters * filter_size * filter_size * num_channels) + num_filters` according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59343843/how-to-compute-number-of-weights-of-cnn), but I'm pretty sure that doesn't work for my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

After tinkering around I was able to come up with a solution when the dimension weights are of size `(1, 1, 4, 4)` or `(num_filters * num_channels * filter_size * filter_size)`. If anyone wants to provide a mathematical or similar explanation, it would be much appreciated!